# Why do I seem to lose control of my computer when full screen Unity game loses focus?

Tags: unity

When I press Ctrl+Alt+Esc or Ctrl+Shift+Esc the game loses focus, but then the whole PC is unusable  and I need to restart the PC to regain control

How do I prevent the computer from locking up (let the player control their PC) when a full screen Unity game loses focus?

Comment: To clarify, a game *you're making* renders the computer unusable when it loses focus? And considering you have to press Ctrl+Shift+Esc, it must be a fullscreen window, right?

Comment: Yes. It's a fullscreen window

Comment: Okay, judging from the tag, you're using Unity. What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Isn't this normally done via alt+tab or the windows key?

Comment: @user2813274 Anything that gives focus to something other than the game will work, and to the game they all work in the same way, so that shouldn't be relevant to the question.

Comment: Currently I have this version: 4.5.0f6

Answer (score 26):

I just tested this myself and confirmed this is a bug with Unity. When a full-screen Unity game loses focus, it still intercepts all input, so any clicks just give focus back to the game. (Without making it reappear, strangely enough.)

This issue was also noted by GG67 in a comment on [this bug report](http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/run-in-background-does-not-work-for-fullscreen), followed by CLEROTH saying he doesn't notice the issue in 4.5.3p1, so you should try updating and see if that fixes anything.

And if updating to 4.5.3p1 or beyond does not fix your problem, you should then report the bug by following [this process](http://unity3d.com/BugReportingFAQ).